# I want to covert MySQL query into Laravel Eloquent / Laravel ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

This is my query;

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `chats` chat
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(`chats`.`id`) AS last_id
    FROM
        `chats`
    WHERE
        (`chats`.`receiver_id` = 1 OR `chats`.`sender_id` = 1)
    GROUP BY
        CONCAT(
            LEAST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            ),
            '.',
            GREATEST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            )
        )
) conversations
ON
    conversations.last_id = chat.id
ORDER BY
    chat.created_at
DESC;
```

I have tried to convert this MySQL query.
*This is what I have done so far;*

```
$query = Chat::query();
$total_records = $query->select("chats.*")
        ->innerJoin('chats', function($join) use ($loggin_user) {
        $join->on('chats.id', '=',DB::raw('( SELECT MAX(`chats`.`id`) AS last_id FROM `chats` WHERE (`chats`.`receiver_id` = '.$loggin_user.' OR `chats`.`sender_id` = '.$loggin_user.') GROUP BY CONCAT( LEAST( `chats`.`receiver_id`, `chats`.`sender_id` ), '.', GREATEST( `chats`.`receiver_id`, `chats`.`sender_id` ) ) )'))
        ->orderBy("chats.created_at", "DESC")->get()->toArray();
});
```

It show this error on screen after querying:

[Errors Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQIaX.png)

I need someone's help to convert this query into Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

use `join` instead of `innerJoin`.
there is no such thing as innerJoin in eloquent you can use this three methods:
`join`, `leftJoin` and `rightJoin`.
i don't know what you're trying to do exactly. try this three methods and see if they work

Comment: Yes, I have tried all kinds of `join`, but getting errors.
I think there is something wrong with my `DB::RAW` statement.
Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: no problem! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Do provide [RAW](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions) functionaltiy where you can execute raw queries as well.

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT
    *
FROM
    `chats` chat
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(`chats`.`id`) AS last_id
    FROM
        `chats`
    WHERE
        (`chats`.`receiver_id` = 1 OR `chats`.`sender_id` = 1)
    GROUP BY
        CONCAT(
            LEAST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            ),
            '.',
            GREATEST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            )
        )
) conversations
ON
    conversations.last_id = chat.id
ORDER BY
    chat.created_at
DESC;");
```

We can still use statement command of Laravel as well

```
$query = DB::statement("SELECT
    *
FROM
    `chats` chat
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(`chats`.`id`) AS last_id
    FROM
        `chats`
    WHERE
        (`chats`.`receiver_id` = 1 OR `chats`.`sender_id` = 1)
    GROUP BY
        CONCAT(
            LEAST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            ),
            '.',
            GREATEST(
                `chats`.`receiver_id`,
                `chats`.`sender_id`
            )
        )
) conversations
ON
    conversations.last_id = chat.id
ORDER BY
    chat.created_at
DESC;");
```

As you asked if you want to use get function with raw queries, you can modify your queries like this:

```
DB::table('some_table')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS result')
    ->get();
```

This will return a collection of PHP objects.

Additional you can use this as well:

```
DB::select(DB::raw(" 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS result
    FROM some_table"
));
```

This will return array of Php object.

Comment: Yes, I already tried both of these RAW statements. Both are working fine.
But I want Database `Model Object` so i can call `->get()`, `->toArray()` and `->count()` functions.
The issue is that with RAW i'm not able to call these laravel model object functions.